# How to use an excludent IN?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following code:

```
SELECT stores_tb.stores, sum(products_tb_tb.prices)
        from products_tb
        inner join stores_tb
        on products_tb.id_store = stores_tb.id_store
        where products_tb.barcode IN ($barcodes)
        group by stores_tb.stores
        order by sum(products_tb.prices)
```

Being the `$barcodes` an array (already converted to a string) that I receive via ajax in a php file that executes the MySQL.

The thing is that the `IN` is inclusive, using `OR` for each of the array values, meaning that if one of the stores required on the `SELECT` have one, but not all of the barcodes in the array, it will be shown.

I wanna know if there is a function like the `IN` (or a way to use the `IN` function) in which it will return only the stores that have all of the barcodes passed in the array, the equvilant of using `AND` instead of `OR` for each of the array values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a `having` clause:

```
select s.stores, sum(p.prices)
from products_tb p join
     stores_tb s
     on p.id_store = s.id_store
where p.barcode IN ($barcodes)
group by s.stores
having count(distinct p.barcode) = $n  -- the number of codes that need to match
order by sum(p.prices);
```

The `$n` value is the length of the `$barcodes` list (strictly speaking, the number of unique items in it).

Comment: On the ``having count(distinct p.id_store) = $n`` you mean ``having count(distinct p.barcode) = $n``, right? That way, it worked. Thank you!

Comment: @allansanfer . . . Yes, that is what it really should be.

Answer (score 0):

Instead  of an array and an IN clause  You could use a subselect and the `ALL`  operator

```
SELECT stores_tb.stores, sum(products_tb_tb.prices)
    from products_tb
    inner join stores_tb
    on products_tb.id_store = stores_tb.id_store
    where products_tb.barcode =  ALL  (
        select barcode from my_table )
     )
    group by stores_tb.stores
    order by sum(products_tb.prices)
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/all-subqueries.html